# Is that possible to increase the total supply of the cardano native tokens on mainnet of already deployed tokens?

Tags: token, assets, lazy-minting

I want to increase the total supply of my cardano native tokens. I have already minted 50000 tokens but I want to mint 500M tokens total, is there any way we can increase total supply. like we have already 50k tokens and now we mint more 500M - 50k tokens that is total 500M tokens should be there. is that possible, if yes then how?

I am trying to increase cradano native tokens total supply.